# Calendar events creation with Podio API

Tags: podio

I was wondering if there is any way to create calendar events through the Podio API, but related with Calendar (https://developers.podio.com/doc/calendar) I cannot find any.

Does anyone knows if it is possible with the Podio API or any other way?

What I want is to create calendar events from a mobile app.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

(I wrote an email with this doubt to Podio but no response after a week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create event item, which will automatically create calendar event.